# Correct verb tense for the sentence (present continuous or passive present simple)

Tags: grammar, tenses

In this sentence:

> Now, after two and half years in the shadow of Covid, for many people
> travel restrictions are ____.

may I use **ending** or **ended** in the blank? or both of them are correct?

Comment: Have all travel restrictions ceased or not?

Comment: There are countries that continue to have some restrictions. @KillingTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you want to convey, both may be correct. Take a look at the following examples. Of course, in this case, **lift** seems more appropriate than **end**.

> [e.g. #1](https://www.forbes.com/sites/alexledsom/2022/05/05/europe-travel-restrictions-more-eu-countries-completely-open-in-may/?sh=70283d95675e): As more and more European travel restrictions **are lifted** heading into the summer, three more countries are doing the same, joining Greece, whose government recently announced that from May 1, travel restrictions would be scrapped.

> [e.g. #2](https://www.cbc.ca/radio/the-same-boat-two-years-into-the-pandemic-families-reunite-1.6500240): Now that travel restrictions **are lifting**, many are reuniting with their relatives.

Comment: Based on @KillingTime, In your first example *e.g. #1*, restrictions are not completely ended. So we should use *are lifting*: *As more and more European travel restrictions are lifting...*

Comment: Conceptually, agree with you but the example comes from an article from Forbes, by the way!